# How to add SSL_RSA to SSLCipherSuite?

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

Really hope for some help in my problem with SSLCipherSuite... So i have this kind of virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /home/webz/site.com
ServerName site.com
ServerAlias www.site.com

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "kEDH:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH:EDH+AESGCM:EDH+aRSA:HIGH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!DH+3DES:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:!RC4"
SSLCompression off

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/site.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/site.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything works fine also security is ok by test. (https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp)

PROBLEM: I am trying to install payment module (REDSYS) for Opencart 2. Redsys support team are not activating payment module because they ask me to add one off SSLCipherSuite below:

SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,
SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

At the moment all SSLCipherSuite starts with TLS... :( So how to add one of those SSLCipherSuites with SSL_RSA... ??? Hope there is somebody who knows good SSL and will help...

Comment: In the [`openssl ciphers` docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/ciphers.html), about 2/3 of the way down the page, you should find listings of the RFC names (such as `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5`) paired up with their OpenSSL-assigned cipher name (like `RC4-MD5`).

Comment: Yes but how to add them in my virtual host???

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration you have such cipher suites already. For example you've included AES256-SHA which is the same as  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA. And the SSL_ prefix instead of the TLS_ prefix is just a convention from the old times where TLS was called SSL (i.e. TLS 1.0 is in effect SSL 3.1).

It is more likely that your restriction to TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 causes the problem, because given that they require you to use such old ciphers and cannot even handle ECDHE ciphers might indicate that they have a very old client which is not able to speak TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.

Of course it might also be that you've included different ciphers in other (i.e. not shown) parts of your server configuration which take precedence. To get information what kind of ciphers your server really supports check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

---

EDIT: The [analysis by SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pro24.es) shows quite clearly that TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (which is the same as SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA or AES256-SHA) is enabled on the server as requested. If my assumption is correct the real problem is that they use an old client which does not speak TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 yet. In this case you could change your configuration for the supported protocol versions to allow TLS 1.0 too:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
```

With this configuration TLS 1.0 and better (i.e. TLS 1.1, TLS 1.2) are supported.

Comment: Main ssl configuration is same SSLCipherSuite. Site is [link]pro24.es[/link]... I really tried lit of variants. But they all time ask to add one of those SSL. I am really weak in ssl questions. So maybe i will try to copy paste your email to them. Thanks a lot for answer ;)

Comment: @RaimondsZundurs: analysis by ssllabs shows that you already support the required cipher. See edited answer for more details.

Comment: Thank you for advise... i made changes to virtualhost also to main ssl config... also i send a message to payment module REDSYS team will see what they gonna say :)) but i think they will answer Monday... will see...

Comment: Hi there got email from module suport team any ideas what to do? EMAIL: All Redsys Cipher suites are supported by SSL, and to not have problems
reporting the certificate must have at least one of these suits SSL
Cipher.

Comment: @RaimondsZundurs: I cannot imagine that this information comes from a person which understands TLS. Certificates don't have ciphers at all. And again, your server supports at least one of the ciphers they requested.

Comment: You was totally right :) problem was that support team is from Spain :) Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: @RaimondsZundurs Did setting the apache directive to "SSLProtocol all -SSLv3"
 solve the issue with redsys? I'm having the same problem.